# Разделить строку по маске

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
12КБ29-ЛБАА
```

надо разбить её на строки используя шаблон регулярных выражений, зная их формат

```
[число][две буквы][цифра][цифра]-[четыре буквы]
```

в результате должен быть массив строк

```
12
КБ
2
9
ЛБАА
```

Возможно ли это вообще с помощью Regex?
Разбивать по шаблону необходимо, потому что есть задача составить словарь выражений и разбивать строки по нему, зная выражение которое относится к данной сроке.

Comment: В середине шаблона `[число][число]` - может там всё-же должно быть `[цифра][цифра]`? Потому что как иначе из одного числа 29 получить два: 2 и 9?

Comment: В строке есть тире, в шаблоне его нет. Как быть? Шаблон не сматчен, данные не найдены.

Comment: Возможно. Используйте группы захвата, которые в круглых скобках

Comment: Исправил шаблон

Answer (score 0):

Разбивка с помощью скобочных групп

```
/^(\d+)([A-ZА-Я]{2})(\d)(\d)-([A-ZА-Я]{4})$/
```